# How do I launch a new cmd window which won't auto close after the execution

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to java in a new cmd window which won't auto close after the execution.

Here is the code in the batch file I tried

```
start CMD /c "java Hello" && "pause"
```

I also tried

```
start CMD /c "java Hello" & "pause"
```

and

```
start cmd /k /c "java Hello" & "pause"
```

Comment: What about opening a Command Prompt window, typing `cmd /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key, to see its usage information? You should see that `/C` and `K` are exclusive, and what each does. For example, `Start %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe" -help"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole set of commands in a single set of quotes, for example

```
start CMD /c "java Hello && pause"
```

or

```
start CMD /c "java Hello & pause"
```

The second, with a single ampersand, will still pause even if the first command fails, whereas the first will close the window before you can read any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)

> /c    Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.

> /k    Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

I think you just need the /k without the /c.  That worked in my simple experiment.